# Preset files are not allowed to export objects

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a carousel file in which I want to get `index.js` and build `block.build.js`, so my `webpack.config.js` is:

```js
var config = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'block.build.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './Carousel'
  },
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test: /.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
          plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

The `package.json` which I use is below:

```json
{
  "name": "carousel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-swipeable": "^4.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "author": "brad traversy",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

… but I get this error message:

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module build failed: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/ helped me.

Comment: I didn't see it in the answers, but I also get this error on projects that need to migrate from babel-preset-es2015 to @babel/preset-env

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You're using a combination of Babel 6 and Babel 7. There is no guarantee of compatibility across versions:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
"babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.2",
"babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
```

should be

```
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
"@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
"babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.2",
"babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
```

and

```
    query: {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
      plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
    }
```

would be

```
    query: {
      presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/es2015'],
      plugins: ['@babel/proposal-class-properties']
    }
```

I'm also confused because you didn't mention `@babel/proposal-class-properties` in your `package.json`, but assuming it is in there it should also be updated.

Comment: I'd highlight that `babel-loader` 8 should be used with those other modules v7 and using `npm install --save-dev babel-loader@^7` gave me other errors

Comment: how to then provide packages that belong to only either babel 6 or 7? I went through all solutions and either then it ask me @babel/core or babel-core. Can the package been changed manually?

Comment: how to then make sure a package that belong to only either babel 6 or 7? I went through all solutions and either then it ask me @babel/core or babel-core. I believe it has to do with node-modules still referencing somehow to wrong babel for a cache issue. I also tried to change manually them without luck

Comment: This situation still happens. So far this tool https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade seems a way when more dependencies to upgrade are presented

Comment: I am still having issues with this error can someone help me? I am trying to run my react app (uses webpack) on an express server. Here is my github repo ( https://github.com/smthmelv/my-react-app/tree/addExpressJS ), any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 55):

It happened to me and a simple solution for me was to uninstall `babel-loader@8^` and `@babel/core`:

```
npm uninstall --save babel-loader
npm uninstall --save @babel/core
```

… and then to install version 7 babel-loader:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-loader@^7
```

Comment: It really worked, thanks alot for this info. I was also using babel/core version 7 and babel-loader version 8. So I just uninstall version 8 and install version 7 with command `npm install --save-dev babel-loader@^7`

Comment: This fixed it for me, though I've not got any other js framework installed.

Comment: I had two different version of babel/core and babel-loader. So I had to uninstall babel-loader having version 8 and install again having version 7. It solved my problem.

Comment: I basically wasting an afternoon because so many packages changes since just few weeks ago when I first setup correctly webpack 2. There is a way to keep track of stable packages?This is not productive at all. I would like to develop react component not keep installing and unistall babel packages

Comment: This works for me though i got another error  which is  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): so am looking forward to solve it

Comment: Incredible as I keep having this issue since many open source projects are quite outdated but refer to babel 6 or a mix with babel 7

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks man. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 12):

Got the same issue in my webpack/react project - it seems that there was an issue with the `.babelrc` file.

I updated it as seen below and it did the trick:

```json
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Also from `babel-loader` v8, they have changed a little bit:

**webpack 4.x | babel-loader 8.x | babel 7.x**

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

**webpack 4.x | babel-loader 7.x | babel 6.x**

```
npm install -D babel-loader@7 babel-core babel-preset-env webpack
```

(same thing for `@babel/preset-react` instead of `babel-preset-react`).

Answer (score 5):

There are upgrades in babel 7 from version 6 refer to https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration. To solve the current problem/error

Install

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react

npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
```

then in .babelrc the dependency for presets should look like

```
{

"presets":["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],

   "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel", "transform-object-rest-spread"]

}
```

Comment: it worked partially formed me. it said that could't find `react-hot-loader/babel`
so I defined like this:
`{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "styled-components",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}`

and worked

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me:

```
npm uninstall --save babel-loader
npm uninstall --save @babel/core
npm install --save-dev babel-loader@^7
```

and in babelrc:

```
"presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
```

Comment: This is not complete to solve this issue at least to remember to install the bridge package that avoid that some hiddend dependency is still "requiring" the previous version, I solved this error after more then an 1 hour thanks to this npm install --save-dev "babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0"  from here https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8482

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me:

```
npm install babel-loader babel-preset-react
```

then in `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

then run `npm run start`, webpack will generate the `dist` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had "stage-1" within my presets in .babelrc, so I removed that and the error went away

Answer (score 1):

in **webpack.config.js** file add

```
module: {
    rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            options: { presets: ['@babel/env','@babel/preset-react'] }
        },
    ]
}
```

and create a file named **.babelrc**

```
{ "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

and in **package.json** must install these *dependencies* and *devDependencies*

```
"dependencies": {
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
   "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
   "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
   "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
   "react": "^17.0.2",
   "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
   "validator": "^13.7.0",
   "webpack": "^5.62.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
   "@types/react": "^17.0.34",
   "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
   "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
   "nodemon": "^2.0.14",
   "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
}
```

first, remove installed packages

if yarn use

```
yarn remove babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-env babel-preset-react
```

if npm use

```
npm uninstall babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-env babel-preset-react
```

**Then install packages**

install using **yarn**

```
yarn add -D @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

install using **npm**

```
npm add -D @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .babelrc file following code this fix my issue

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me using Yarn was:

```
yarn add babel-loader babel-preset-react @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react -D
```

then in .babelrc.json or only .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

then run `webpack` or `yarn webpack`, it'll generate the `dist` on the project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly seems like you're facing issues due to the non-compatibility of babel-preset-react and babel-preset-env modules. These modules are now obsolete so you may need to install their latest alternatives. @babel/core seems to be fine.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Remove all the old babel-related modules. Although it's not necessary to remove all of them but I would suggest you start with a clean slate.

```js
yarn remove babel-preset-react babel-preset-env
```

Or if you're using npm then enter the following code in the terminal:

```js
npm uninstall babel - preset - react babel - preset - env
```

Once the old modules are removed, install the new ones. I'm showing codes for both yarn and npm

```js
yarn add @babel/core @babel/preset-react @babel/preset/env --save

npm i @babel/core @babel/preset-react @babel/preset/env --save
```

Note that even if you already have @babel/core module installed, reinstall it as it helped me run my code for whatever reasons.

After that, as a final step, go ahead and edit your .babelrc file with this code:

```js
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

Comment: shouldn't installation line  read "npm i @babel/core @babel/preset-react @babel/preset-env --save" rather than "npm i @babel/core @babel/preset-react @babel/preset/env --save" ?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this error for build (npm run build) for the last one week and with all of the available resources and the tips from stackoverflow also did not work for me. Finally as it was earlier suggested from stackoverflow on the .babelrc file in the src folder where the presets we should define only the code given below:

```
{
   "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins":
        ["transform-class-properties", "transform-object-rest-spread",
         "@babel/plugin-proposal-import-attributes-to-assertions"]
}
```

Since @babel-core present in the package.json file we do not need to mention the statement in the above code viz., "react", "es2015", "stage-0". After commenting the viz., part of line shown above my problem got solved.  Finally my code build without any errors.