# Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

This is my first React Native project. The repo is [here](https://github.com/dancancro/questions).

When I start up [expo](https://expo.io/), I get the error:

```
Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react'
```

Among [others](https://github.com/dancancro/questions/blob/master/package.json), it has these dependencies:

```
"expo": "^32.0.0",
"react": "16.8.4",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.1.tar.gz",
"@babel/core": "7.3.4",
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
```

I found these four libraries in my app's /node_modules that each contain a dev dependency on "babel-preset-react":

> hoist-non-react-statics,  prop-types,  react-input-autosize and 
>   react-proxy.

None of these have newer versions that depend on "@babel/preset-react".

Answer (score 6):

I had to change `['react']` to `['@babel/preset-react']` in `.bablerc` when upgrading from babel 6.x to 7.x:

```json
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this a few, every time I install a new module/plugin.
My solution has been to delete node_modules folder and yarn install or npm install.

It stops the error. I'm not sure is the right solution (would be interested to know if it is), but works.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me perfectly. After hours of looking everywhere for solutions, and installing a bunch of (probably unnecessary, who knows) packages, the solution is so simple and clean.

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue to do with an expo project being in a bad state.

Expo is an express set of libs with the goal of simplifying development, but it is not compatible with most react native examples in the wild.

After further review, it looks like you may have followed a regular react native example in an Expo based project, without first ejecting.

Comment: Interesting. So I added babel-preset-react (in addition to @babel/preset-react) and got the error: "Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions." That led me to this, which didn't solve the problem or suggest that an app should include both packages. https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/540#issuecomment-344023061

Comment: out of curiosity, could you try removing `"babel-preset-expo"` from the presets in package.json?

Also, have you tried to eject this project? It's kind of looking to me like a project that's been ejected but is still trying to use expo. I'm not suggesting to eject, there is no going backwards from that, just curious if that's what's going on here.

Comment: Same thing. The error refers to babel-preset-react:Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/Dan/work/b/questions/node_modules/babel-preset-react/lib/index.js

Comment: I have not tried ejecting. I got where I am by following the new React Native app instructions. It worked fine at that point. Then I copied into it files from a simple React app and modified a few things.

Comment: I tried cloning and building your project, but I didn't resolve the issue. I feel it's because you're following articles for react native and not for expo.

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying! Such is the nature of distributed invention. I'll look around for a good expo example. If you have any favorites please let me know.

Comment: I only used expo for a few days before my needs were more than it could handle, I found it very limiting. I suggest if you want to do some more advanced things, or anything custom on the native side at all, to eject right away. After ejecting, you will not have any of the expo libs, and would need to re-implement existing work, so ejecting down the line is a bit of a trap; eject right away or never at all. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I don't think is really connected to expo or react native, is a mismatching regarding dependencies regarding babel 6 and babel 7 or using both as from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182862/preset-files-are-not-allowed-to-export-objects

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure the babel config has '@babel/preset-react' in presets and not 'babel-preset-react'

Apart from that. this did it for me:

```
npm i @babel/preset-react 

npm i @babel/core
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue wherein I mistyped `babel/preset-react` as `babel-preset-react` in the babel config file.

Correcting the typo helped me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after an upgrade. I needed a restart and it was solved. Apparently some caching issue or running process which still uses an old dependency.