# Babel-Loader Error Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

After updating all my outdated `npm` packages to `@latest`, my electron app fails to start, giving the error

> ERROR in ./src/index.js
>   [0] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>   [0] Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/nyxynyx/foobar/node_modules/babel-preset-stage-0/lib/index.js

Any idea what went wrong? Thank you everyone!

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-styled-components",
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    ["transform-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

**package.json (dependencies & devDependencies)**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.21",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-log": "^3.0.7",
    "electron-updater": "^4.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "firebase": "^6.3.4",
    "fix-path": "^2.1.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "menubar": "^6.0.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^2.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "typeface-open-sans": "0.0.75",
    "url-loader": "^2.1.0"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.1",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^6.0.1",
    "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
    "electron-debug": "^3.0.1",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.10",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "stylelint": "^10.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.3.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
  },
```

*Using node v12.6.0 on Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.5*

Comment: Why your `babel-core` is `6.26.3` but your presets are `6.24.1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preset files are not allowed to export objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182862/preset-files-are-not-allowed-to-export-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am moving my answer from comment due to lack of space there :)

Try using new packages for babel-core, babel-register and presets, replacing the old ones since they are depricated (babel-core, babel-presets-env, etc):

@babel/core - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/core,

@babel/presets-env - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env,

@babel/presets-react - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react,

@babel/presets-stage-0 https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-0,

@babel/polyfill - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill and

@babel/register - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register.

Then try deleting package.lock, and running again npm i . If that is not helping you can also try deleting node_modules folder, and running npm i again

Comment: Works! Also had to update `.babelrc`, where `npx babel-upgrade --save --write` helps. `@babel/presets-stage-0` was uninstalled too as it has been deprecated.

Comment: Not working for me, I'm using ubuntu and node v11.5.0. Following error I'm getting:

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                            1:40:15 PM

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/app.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /home/vagrant/code/mypos/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/lib/index.js

Answer (score 2):

`babel-preset-env` / `babel-preset-react` packages are deprecated.
use `@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/preset-react` packages.

And do the following change in `.babelrc` :

```
"presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is due to **outdated babel packages** being used. The babel project, just like most other active Javascript projects, have moved on to using scope packages. Hence, the package names starts with `@babel`

[Check this to fix issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62089763/10907720)