# webpacker Uncaught Error: Module build failed / Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, babeljs, webpacker

In setting up webpacker with my Rails 5.2.4 app, I've introduced this bug to my browser console: `Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import' from '/Users/me/code/project' - Did you mean "@babel/syntax-dynamic-import"`

`@babel/syntax-dynamic-import` is not a real package, so what does this mean? Looking through that `index.js` file I see no mention of `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`. Furthermore, said plugin is stored in `node_modules/@babel/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182862/preset-files-are-not-allowed-to-export-objects) I made sure that all my babel packages were on version 7. Except for `babel-loader` v8, because v7 was looking for an incorrect dependency.

My `package.json` looks alright as far as I can tell:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "micromodal": "^0.4.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "semantic-ui": "2.4.2",
    "uppy": "^1.21.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

Also, there is no leftover .babelrc file in my root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to downgrade `babel-loader@8.1.0` to `babel-loader@8.0.6`

Comment: Can you please share the npm command for this

Comment: i didn't use one, i opened package.json and changed it manually